# How to display the innerHtml contents of newly created element

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
        function Eval(a){
         var element= document.createElement('p');   // Creating a paragraph  
         $(element).addClass("output-class");
         element.innerHTML+= a; }
```

The contents added are not displayed even after styling "output-class" dynamically or even within  tag. But if I write console.log(element) then I get the required result but not on the webpage.

Comment: Please take a few minutes to read [ask] and update question with a [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: Because where exactly do you add that element to the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You almost there, three main considerations:**

- You don't need jQuery to add a classname, use `classList` instead.
- You don't need to use this statement `element.innerHTML += a;` because this is a newly created element, so the `innerHTML` attribute is empty.  Use this `element.innerHTML = a;` instead
- **To make that element visible/rendered, you need to add it to a parent element.  To accomplish that, use the function [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)**.

*In this example, the parent is the body element.*

```js
function Eval(a, parent) {
  var element = document.createElement('p'); // Creating a paragraph  
  element.classList.add("output-class");
  element.innerHTML = a;
  
  parent.appendChild(element);
}

Eval('Ele from SO', document.body)
```

```css
.output-class {
  font-size: 24px
}
```

Comment: One more question. I am adding this function as the onclick property of a button. So whenever I press the button the text in 'a' is superimposed on the previous one whereas I want it to have some space. I added left margin in the css but nothing is working. Can you help me out ?

Comment: @Anshkapoor can you create a jsfiddle snippet to understand your scenario?

Comment: @ Ele Actually I am making a calculator which solves algebraic equations as a beginner project so I dont have any idea how to proceed as it is my first project I need a human help